# Problem with custom recurrent version of ls command

Tags: bash, recursion, ls

I have no idea why the example from Learning the Bash shell does not work. It is supposed to be recursive variant of `ls` command. What it does is printing only the name of directory and that's all. Any hints?

```
recdir ()
{
   tab=$tab$singletab
   for file in "$@"; do
    echo -e $tab$file
    thisfile=$thisfile/$file
    if [ -d "$thisfile" ]; then
       recdir $(command ls $thisfile)
    fi
    thisfile=${thisfile%/*}
    done
tab=${tab%"$singletab"}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, that script is broken: it won't work correctly if a filename contains a white space character. Also, the use of `echo -e` is not a recommended practice. In order to make it work for filenames that don't contain white space characters, the function must be called like `recdir /path/to/directory`. But before that, the variable `singletab` should be initialized something like this: `singletab='\t'`. Below is a corrected version of that script (in pure `bash`, without using `ls`):

```
#!/bin/bash

recdir()
{
    for file in "$@"; do
        [ -e "$file" ] && printf '%s%s\n' "$tabs" "$file"
        if [ -d "$file" ]; then
            local curdir=$PWD
            cd "$file" && { tabs=$tabs$'\t'; recdir *; tabs=${tabs%?}; }
            cd "$curdir"
        fi
    done
}

recdir "$@"
```